# Posting to same page with jquery.ajax, no vars passing.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm grabbing the onclick event for a specific #id and then sending the relevant form data to the same page( to itself ), checking to see whether $_POST['submit'] is set, if it is I'm sending an email.

It I don't get any errors but I get no data sent via post it seems.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').keyup(username_check);

    $('#clickarea').click(submit_form);


});

function submit_form(){
    var login =  $('#login').val();
    var comment = $('#message').val();
    var spt = $('#spam_prevention_test').val();
    var submit = #('submit').val();
    alert('You got here');  <-- Yes i get the alert so its making it to the function
    jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "sign_up.php",
    data: 'login='+ login+'message='+ comment+'spt='+ spt+'submit'+ submit,
    cache: false
    });

}
</script>
```

I tried setting submit to .val, to 1, to "1" thinking it just needed to be set to something.
I did a quick echo in the header to see if I'd get any of the var's and no I don't.

```
echo "Var" . $_POST['login'];  <-- just returns blank

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  <-- never makes it into here.
```

What am I missing here, is there something special I need to do to pass back to the same page?

Comment: The current page will not be updated because you did an Ajax call. You need to Update the DOM manually after getting response from the page you sent the request to.

Comment: What does your html form look like?

Comment: My lack of reading was the issue.  Ajax is not what i needed, it was doing exactly what it should have. As always.. RTFM first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `success` handler function that will read the response to the HTTP request made by `$.ajax` and do something with it.

Comment: I think maybe I'm using the wrong thing here.  Going to go back to using         $('#clickarea').click(function() {  
                $("#contactform").submit();   
        });  That seemed to work.